# spring-boot / spring-data-jpa custom query filtering by Date field returning results without filtering

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a spring-boot REST server using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.2.RELEASE. I have the following POJO class hierarchy. First the base class Entity:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Entity implements Serializable {    

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 48)
    public String id = UNINITIALIZED_ID;

    /**
     * The timestamp for when this entity was last updated.
     */
    @Column(columnDefinition = "timestamp with time zone")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date updateTimestamp = new Date();

}
```

Next the concrete sub-class Patient:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(indexes={@Index(columnList="updateTimestamp")})
public class Patient extends Entity {
...
}
```

I define my PatientRepository interface as follows with a custom method to fetch patients whose updateTimestamp is after a specified timestamp:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "patients", path = "patients")
public interface PatientRepository extends JpaRepository<Patient, String> {
    List<Patient> findByUpdateTimestampAfter(@DateTimeFormat(iso=DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)@Param("after")Date after);
}
```

For some unknown reason the filter by updateTimestamnp is not working when I issue the following GET request via Advanced Rest Client Chrome plugin:

```
// url example. DateFormat matches @DateTimeFormat on param in query method. 
GET http://127.0.0.1:8090/patients?after=2030-01-10T00:00:00.000-05:00
```

I expect only those entities that have updateTimestamp after specified timestamp to be returned but what I get is ALL the entities in the resource collection instead.

I have turned on DEBUG logging on spring-boot. Here is something that I am not sure is an issue:

```
2017-05-18 10:15:56.127 DEBUG 5292 --- [           main] o.s.d.j.r.query.JpaQueryFactory          : Looking up query for method findByUpdateTimestampAfter
2017-05-18 10:15:56.132 DEBUG 5292 --- [           main] o.s.d.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery    : Looking up named query Patient.findByUpdateTimestampAfter
2017-05-18 10:15:56.133 DEBUG 5292 --- [           main] o.s.d.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery    : Did not find named query Patient.findByUpdateTimestampAfter
```

Based on good suggestion from @pvpkiran I wroite the following Spock integration test and showed that aftergetting the Date to parse I the PatientRepository.findByUpdateTimestampAfter method works as expected:

```
    @SpringBootTest(classes = com.altran.medmap.server.Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    @Transactional

class PatientRepositorySpec extends Specification {


    @Autowired
    PatientRepository patientRepository;


    @Bean
    @Unroll    
    def 'Should GET #size patients whose updateTimestamp is after: #after'( {
        given:
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat('MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a');
            Date afterx = dateFormat.parse(after);
        when:
            List<Patient> result = patientRepository.findByUpdateTimestampAfter(after);
        then:
          result.size() == size;
        where: 'result size matches expected'
            after                        | size
            'Jan 1, 2016 00:00:00 AM'    | 2
            'Jan 1, 2030 00:00:00 AM'    | 0

    }            
}
```

The fact that the REST API is still returning all entities is still an unsolved mystery. Not that I have specified @DateTimeFormat(iso=DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) on query method param in Repository interface and using the same format in rest URL. Any suggestions where to go from here?

Comment: when you say not working does it mean no records are fetched or are you getting any exceptions. Do you have records matching this criteria in DB?

Comment: So sorry. Just updated that I am getting all entities and not the subset that have updateTimestamp after the specified timestamp.

Comment: remove your `@Query` and try. Spring data is intelligent enough to formulate a query by method name. I think the issue is with the way you are comparing using `>`. So leave those complexities to framework. Just try without @ Query

Comment: Thank @pvpkiran. That gives me same result of returning all entities instead of subset. I see the following in log:

2017-05-18 09:25:22.580 DEBUG 14192 --- [           main] o.s.d.j.r.query.JpaQueryFactory          : Looking up query for method findByUpdateTimestampAfter
2017-05-18 09:25:22.585 DEBUG 14192 --- [           main] o.s.d.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery    : Looking up named query Patient.findByUpdateTimestampAfter
2017-05-18 09:25:22.586 DEBUG 14192 --- [           main] o.s.d.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery    : Did not find named query Patient.findByUpdateTimestampAfter

Comment: public Date updateTimestamp = new Date(); why are you initializing date object here?

Comment: I was trying to avoid dealing with null value cases. It should not matter since my query is searching with after date in next year so no objects should match. Why should it matters if I initialize or not? Confused.

Comment: I think the problem is with your mapping. You either use `@MappedSuperclass` or `@Inheritance`. Both together don't make sense

Comment: Good point @pvkirant. I removed MappedSuperClass and added javax.persistence.Entity to class (see updated original post) . Still no change in behavior.

Comment: Did you also removed @Query? Are you still getting same NamedQuery exception?Are you passing the date in the correct format?. And one last thing, can you call this repository from a Test Code and not from chrome and see if anything changes?

Comment: Yes I did remove @Query and saw no change (just updated OP). I am and was not previously seeing any exceptions. It was just a log message. which I will add to OP.
The date format seems to be correct and is actually copied from the column data in db verbatim. I will write a unit test to see if anything changes. Thanks for the great suggestions.

Comment: @pvpkiran Writing a unit test (see updated OP) showed that there was a java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date because my date format did not match what was expected. After fixing it, the PatientRepository works. The rest interface still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the dumb mistake that was causing the rest interface to not give filtered results. My URL path was not correct.

```
//Incorrect URL
http://127.0.0.1:8090/patients?after=2030-01-10T00:00:00.000-05:00

//Correct URL based on spring-data-rest default conventions
http://127.0.0.1:8090/patients/search/findByUpdateTimestampAfter?after=2030-01-10T00:00:00.000-05:00
```

Note that after fixing the URL I am getting a Date parse error. I have created a new question for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059153/spring-data-rest-query-giving-unparseable-date-when-query-param-matches-date).

My thanks to @pvpkiran and @Afridi for their kind help.